# Blend for Visual Studio 11: no project types

Tags: expression-blend, visual-studio-2012

I seem to be having issues with Blend.

When I launch the application I don't seem to have support for XAML:

[image: No XAML :(]

Anybody who ran in this issue?

I've tried adding 'VisualStudioVersion' = '11.0' to the System Environment variables, but no luck :(

I have Windows 7 x64 SP1 (legal!).

Comment: Is this installed on Windows 7 or Windows 8?  (From the rounded corners of the window, I'm guessing Windows 7.)

Comment: Excuse me, forgot to put that in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Blend for Visual Studio 11 Beta only supports Metro style applications (both XAML and HTML).  These projects can only be designed on Windows 8.